# MODULE_NOT_FOUND after typescript transpilation

Tags: javascript, typescript, build, tsconfig

I am getting this error after building my typescript app and starting the app.js:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1050
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'controllers'
```

I think the problem is related to how I am using import / export, for example this is how I am importing on ts:

```
import {
    checkToken,
    getUserInfo,
    signIn,
    signUp
} from 'controllers';
```

but the Javascript dist is using:

```
const controllers_1 = require("controllers");
```

this is my ts.config:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2020",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "rootDirs": ["src"],
        "baseUrl": "./src"
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change in ts.config [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2020",
        "module": "es2020", // you can use es2020 or esnext
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "rootDirs": ["src"],
        "baseUrl": "./src"
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Now it returns a similar error now:

node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'routes' imported from /home/lucas/Documents/projects/DRIVEN/projeto-autoral/projeto22-autoral-back/dist/app.js

Comment: try to add '.js'  as an extension to file

Comment: sorry I ddn`t mention earlier, controllers is a folder and it has an index.ts file that exports all the files from the controllers folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).